# Heroku image crashes after a minute reactjs

Tags: node.js, reactjs, heroku

I have this hotel reservation project with CRUD operation. everything is working fine, after heroku deployment i tried to create new room, upload image. Image was fine and displayed properly but after a minute or so it becames a broken image. i don't know why.
This happen in my server side only. but images for display on my frontend are working fine.

I don't know what's wrong, but i'm pretty sure my codes are okay because after uploading the image displays properly and then crash after 5mins or more. maybe about .git or i don't know.

here's in my Client side

MenuPage.jsx

```
    <img style={{ objectFit: "cover", height: "400px", width: "100%" }} src={ NodeServerURL + 
    room.imageLocation }/>
```

my Function to add new room

```
        addRoom: (parent, args) => {
        let base64String = args.base64EncodedImage
        let base64Image = base64String.split(';base64,').pop()
        let imageLocation = 'images/' + uuid() + '.png'

        fs.writeFile(imageLocation, base64Image, { encoding: 'base64' }, (err) => {})

        let room = new Room({
            roomType: args.roomType,
            roomPrice: args.....
```

here's my deployed website if you wanat to see. all images i uploaded are broken images except the one on the last because that was a recent upload but maybe after a minute it will turn into broken image too.

http://boncales-twth-frontend.herokuapp.com/MenuPage

Answer (score 0):

Heroku's filesystem is ephemeral/short lived. Meaning, any files you save will disappear after you redeploy your app. This explains why only the most recent images work. You can't rely on Heroku's filesystem to store files that need to persist for a longer time.

To store your images, you can look at 3rd party storage solutions such as Cloudinary or AWS S3.